# Javascript Rich Text Editor in Flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript

How do I embedded a HTML-enabled javascript editor on top of Flex web application?

FCKEditor is not free but any free editor with basic toolbar will do?

Answer (score 0):

It is known as the iFrane trick.  If you Google around for it, you'll find it described in a bunch of blogs.

http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex+iframe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Or this project on Google Code: 
http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

There is also an HTML Flex Component from the company Drumbeat Insight.  It tries to address a lot of issues with this approach.